# The coordinates of the svg in css file

Tags: svg

Please tell me how to write the coordinates from the svg polygon, polyline, or path d in css ?

What would you do coordinates to write in css like so :

```html
       #poly{
          fill:yellow;
          stroke:green;
          stroke-width:3px;
          points="50 30, 80 30, 40 100";
        }
```

Comment: Browsers mostly don't support this yet. Chrome does but its syntax for paths is non-standard.

Comment: @RobertLongson very badly. .. write it down as a response ..I'll take it